# Include in a .tpl does not work

Tags: smarty, prestashop, smarty3, prestashop-1.6

This does not display:

```
include {php} echo "hello" {/php}
```

`Smarty.class.php` and `smarty_security.php` I have `$allow_php_tag = true;` but `{php} echo "hello" {/php}` not work. No display "hello" on my side.

Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP in Smarty templates is not recommended and has been deprecated in Smarty 3.1 
However if you really need to use PHP in Smarty template you need to use `SmartyBC` class and not `Smarty` class. To do that:

1. Go to `config/smarty.config.inc.php`
2. Change

`require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');`

into

`require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');`

3. Change

`$smarty = new Smarty();`

into

`$smarty = new SmartyBC();`

That's it. You don't need to do anything more (tested in Prestashop 1.6.0.8)